# Firebase for app flavors for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

What would be the best approach to set up Firebase for app flavors that we will publish in the stores? Use a single project with four apps (two for Android and two for iOS) or 2 different projects, one for each flavor with its apps?

I have read in different places that people use 2 different projects, but why would Firebase allow me to set up more apps in a single project?

The two flavors are the same, but they use different icons and app names for branding, and the website (domain name) and business name are the same for both.

I am concerned about the Dynamic Links, Hosts and Messaging, as we have all those well set up in our current project.

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

If the flavors are essentially variants of the same app, you should typically put them in a single project. Internally we often describe this as: you should have a separate project for each logo.

#### Examples of scenarios that typically go into a single project

So if you have a free and a paid tier of the same app/game, those should typically be in the same project. Same for if you have a variant for a regular user, and one for administrators/super-users or students/teachers. And of course this applies to iOS, Android and other platform variants too: these are considered the same logo, so it's typically best to put them in a single project. That way you can share (user and other) data between the variants, get analytics for all of them in a single property, and more.

#### Examples of scenarios that should go into separate projects

But if you have two different brands whose only commonality is that you want to send push notifications to them, they should be in two different projects. Same for if you have two separate games, where the common factor is that you happen to make both of them. In both of those cases you should keep the data of the apps separate, and create a separate project for each of them.